# How can I improve my use of RaphaëlJS image animation?

Tags: javascript, performance, web, raphael

I'm using RaphaëlJS for rotating an image forever. You can see the current result [here](http://www.mangoprotocol.com). However, I'm experiencing some performance issues after resizing the browser window many times.

Could it be that new animations are created every time the window is resized while old ones are not removed? If that's the case, how can I stop and remove them? If not the case, any idea about how I could improve the performance?

The code is this:

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML>
<html>
  <head>
    <style>
      body {
        background-color: black;
        width: 100%;
        height: 100%;
        margin: 0px;
        padding: 0px;
    }     
    </style>  
    <script type="text/javascript" src="raphael.js"></script>
  </head>
  <body>
    <canvas id="canvas"></canvas>
    <script>
        var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas'); 
        canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
        canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

        var gearImageSrc = "images/gear.png";
        var nikaImageSrc = "images/nika_half.png";
        var logoImageSrc = "images/logo_mp.png";

        var paper;
        var gearImage = new Image();
        var nikaImage = new Image();
        var logoImage = new Image();
        gearImage.src = gearImageSrc;
        nikaImage.src = nikaImageSrc;
        logoImage.src = logoImageSrc;

        showAll = function () {         
            paper = Raphael(0, 0, canvas.width,canvas.height);
            gear = paper.image(gearImageSrc, canvas.width/2 - gearImage.width/4, canvas.height/2 - gearImage.height/3, gearImage.width/2, gearImage.height/2);
            nika = paper.image(nikaImageSrc, canvas.width/2 - nikaImage.width/4, canvas.height/2 - nikaImage.height/3, nikaImage.width/2, nikaImage.height/2);
            logo = paper.image(logoImageSrc, canvas.width/2 - logoImage.width/4, canvas.height/2 + gearImage.height/6, logoImage.width/1.5, logoImage.height/1.5);          
            var spin = Raphael.animation({transform: "r-360"}, 10000).repeat(Infinity);
            gear.animate(spin);
        }       

        function resizeCanvas() {
            canvas.width = window.innerWidth;
            canvas.height = window.innerHeight;

            paper.remove();
            showAll();
        }

        window.addEventListener('resize', resizeCanvas, false);

        window.onload = function () {
            showAll();
        }

    </script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: I just checked the site. it did not seem to do the weird things you are saying. Maybe change 10000 to 15000 for more fluidity

Comment: Have you tried to resize several times? Changing the time value would make the gear spin slowly, and that's not what I want.

Comment: I recommend you do any animation with TweenMax JS from greensock, you won't get any slow down with this.

Comment: oh, i see now, CAN YOU CREATE JSFIDDLE? Because it is hard to say what is wrong without working with the code. Just make a demo that would do something similar

Answer (score 0):

I might have a solution for it, just let me know if this works:

```
var spin = Raphael.animation({transform: "...r-360"}, 10000).repeat(Infinity);
```

You have to add `...` in your transform() whenever you want to append to your transform, which you seem to be doing by re-sizing the window.